# Hapi can't get cookie after redirect until I refresh the page

Tags: cookies, hapi.js

If I set a cookie in one route

```
request.yar.set('example', sessionData);
return reply.redirect('/auth/twitter/welcome');
```

Then get the cookie in /auth/twitter/welcome route

```
console.log('example', request.yar.get('example'));
```

... undefined is returned until I refresh the page.

Please can anyone tell me if I should use the redirect in a different way to pass the cookie data, with a further refresh.

Comment: @CollinD corrected thanks